# How to tar all the files in the directory but not the directory itself

Tags: python-3.x, tarfile

I want to tar all the files in the specified directory. But I don't want to get the directory tar'ed also not the sub-directories too. Currently I have this

```
>>> import tarfile
>>> with tarfile.open("x.gz","w:gz") as tar:
...     tar.add("a", arcname=os.path.basename("a")) #a is the directory
```

But it is tar'ing the directory and sub-directories too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll have to iterate over the contents of the directory and add each file in there one by one:

```
for elem in os.scandir('a'):
    if elem.is_file:
        tar.add(elem.path)
```